# mass e-mail sender

Tags: email, web-applications, software, recommendations

I have a database with 3000+ emails and I want to send a HTML email to all of them.

I don't want to be treated as spam emails, also to have the possibility to attach a pdf file.

Could someone recommend me a web application or a software which can do this job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com)

Answer (score 0):

[**AJ Bulk Mailer**](http://www.ajsquare.com/resources/bulk_mail.php) is the best free bulk mailing software to send mass mails.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mailjet.com/ Cloud Mailing Solution with strong API